# netbeans plugins for jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, netbeans, ide

I am looking for the netbeans jquery plugins.

Please drop me best jquery plugins available for netbeans

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the netbeans forums:

> The latest (of today) Visual Studio
>   documented jQuery file can be
>   downloaded here: 
>   http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/downloads/detail?name=jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js
>
> I keep this copy as a separate copy to
>   the minified version in my "js"
>   directory, my scripts use the minified
>   version, Netbeans can get all the
>   documentation from the VS documented
>   file.
>
> In your scripts make sure to link to
>   the minified files, as the documented
>   file is of course a lot bigger than
>   the minified one.